# REST API - with ordered execution (Spring boot)

Tags: rest, spring-boot, concurrency, request, response

we are building rest API with spring boot.

We have a scenario where we cannot execute requests for a object in parallel. Actually, in back-end, parallel execution is not possible for same objects.

Example  :

```
Not supported in parallel
    Request 1 for action XYZ for object A
    Request 2 for action XYZ for object A
    Request 3 for action ABC for object A

Supported in parallel
    Request 1 for action XYZ for object A
    Request 2 for action XYZ for object B
    Request 3 for action ABC for object C
```

So, I am looking best possible ways to achieve this scenario. one major drawback I can see is that it wont keep the rest application stateless.

I can think of doing this by making  a set where I can track which object entry already exists. If yes then dont accept request for that object.  But with this, I will have to reject the similar request.

Other option where I dont have to reject the request is to maintain a queue where I execute request in a certain object for same object.

But I can sense that this is not the right way to do this. So, if anybody has solved similar situation, please guide.

Comment: REST is stateless, so if you still want to do REST, you might "ACCEPT" (202) a request and process it asynchronously instead of synchronously ("OK", 200) - and during async execution you could well use a queue or a map to prevent multiple requests for the same object and the client can check later whether the request has been finished in the meantime.

Comment: @Smutje the problem which I m facing is to how to tract the request and corresponding  response  if I am using a queue. the dequeuer will dequeue and process the request but then how the response will be tracked

Comment: Generate a UUID for each request and return it to the original requesting thread via a HTTP response (or even produce a URL to return) and later on, the client can use this UUID to check on his original request. Lookup "correlation ID".